# Calculating wells by county and then updating county table with that data using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I have the following code to calculate the number of wells within a counties layer.  Right now it is giving me a total number of wells.

Where and how do I get it to loop through all the counties separately and give me that count separately?

Following this; I'd like to also calculate the well density – i.e. how many wells there are per area unit, and update the table with that value as well.

```
import arcpy

# For each county calculate the total numbers of wells that fall into that county, and update the county table with the total count.

wellsLayer = "C:\\Wells.shp"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(wellsLayer , "wells_lyr")

countiesLayer = "C:\\COUNTIES.shp"

arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("wells_lyr", "INTERSECT", countiesLayer, "", "NEW_SELECTION")

fieldList = "name"

wellsCount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("wells_lyr").getOutput(0))

print wellsCount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a spatial join analysis the output shapefile adds a new field `"Join_Count"` by default in which you can find how many wells are located in each county.

The following example use `arcpy.da.SearchCursor()` to give the information about the number of wells in each county after performing the Spatial join analysis.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = r"F:\Test"

targetFeature = "county.shp"
joinFeature = "well.shp"

arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(targetFeature,joinFeature,"SpatialJoinTest.shp")

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("SpatialJoinTest.shp",["id","Join_Count"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        county_id = row[0]
        well_count = row[1]
        print "There are {0} wells in county id {1}".format(well_count, county_id)

del row
del cursor
```

Te output is like this:

```
There are 0 wells in county id 0
There are 31 wells in county id 1
There are 933 wells in county id 2
There are 548 wells in county id 3
There are 8 wells in county id 4
There are 222 wells in county id 5
```